Adding a Wine `.lnk` Program to Rofi
I was able to add a program (KaTrain) — which I installed with pipx — to Rofi, following this nice answer:
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/home/phili/.local/bin/katrain
Type=Application
Categories=Go
Name=KaTrain

But now, I'm trying ot add another program (Fox Weiqi), which I was only able to install via Wine.
[Desktop Entry]
Exec="wine /home/phili/Other\ Software/Fox\ Weiqi/Fox\ Go\ Server.lnk"
Type=Application
Categories=Go
Name=Fox Weiqi

If I use that Wine command on a terminal, it does work. (I'm using Archcraft.)

The desktop file specification has a special description of the
Exec=
syntax. It seems you should just double-quote the argument if it contains
reserved characters, such as space. Try:
Exec=wine "/home/phili/Other Software/Fox Weiqi/Fox Go Server.lnk"

